# Opencart Hide Div on Page Title - PHP

Tags: php, html, hide, opencart

I have an opencart category page that I am trying to hide the title DIV for.  Out of all the categories and sub cats there is (for now) only one that I am trying to hide.

The following code I have used does not work:

```
<?php if ($categories && $heading_title!="HEADING TITLE HERE") { ?>

    <?php elseif : ?>

<div id="headerhide" style="width:800px;">
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>

<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if ($categories && $heading_title!="HEADING TITLE HERE") { ?>

    <?php }
          else {  
    ?>

<div id="headerhide" style="width:800px;">
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ($categories && $heading_title!="HEADING TITLE HERE") {  } else {  ?>
<div id="headerhide" style="width:800px;">
    <h1><?=$heading_title?></h1>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I have this setup on my OpenCart `information.tpl` page:

```
<?
// If FAQs page or content show AJAX
// We check for case sensitive titles - the title is case sensitive
if($heading_title=="FAQs" || $heading_title=="Faqs") { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // ETC
});
</script>
<?
// Not the FAQs page so do nothing
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently made a commercial vQmod that will be of use to you for this. It's called [Custom Templates](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=8056) and will allow you to assign it to as many individual category pages as you want. It works for more than just categories too (manufacturer, product and info pages). While it may be a bit overkill for one page, if you plan on using it for multiple pages in the future it will be better in the long run in my opinion